# Cypress - set global variable from function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, cypress

I have the following flow:

1) On one page I get the value of a field:

```
 var myID;
 cy.get('#MYID').
        then(($txt) => {
            myID=  $txt.text();
        })
       .should('not.equal', null);
```

2) I then navigate to a new page and try to check if this new page contains this id:

```
cy.get('#myTable').find('td').contains(myID);
```

It says that myID is not defined. I know the first function is async and reading the documentation it says I can use an alias. The problem with the alias is it needs to be in the beforeEach() function which not to go into a long story I cannto use in this test case. I tried using async/await but it did not seem to work for me as it was still undefined.

Comment: "_I then navigate to a new page_" If you load a new page, all the content of the previous page is gone, including JS variables.

Comment: As I understand from your question, the '#MYID'  is avaiable in one page, let us call page 1 and `#myTable` is in a different page...is that correct  ?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Essentially I need to extract myID's value from page 1 and check if it exists inside of the table on page 2

Comment: Ok..got it, create a function to return the 'id' in commands.js file and call in page2.testspec file...let me know if you are stuck in that ...

Comment: @soccerway Thank you, I am new to cypress and was unaware of this file. I tried it last night following the docs https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html, but I was unable to get it to work. I am unsure how to "return" it or if I'm even using the file correctly.

Answer (score 5):

The basic problem here is that Cypress commands run asynchronously from the test code that creates them. You can see this if you put console logs into your code,

```js
var myID;
cy.get('#MYID')
  .then(($txt) => {
    myID=  $txt.text();
    console.log('1', myID);
  })
 .should('not.equal', null); 

console.log('2', myID);
```

This prints out

```
2 undefined
1 myText
```

You can use an alias to overcome this and pass a value down the command chain.

See this [section of the docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Aliases) which shows a similar pattern of code you are using in the DO NOT USE THIS example.

**BUT** aliases get cleared down between tests, so you should set up a `beforeEach()` to obtain a new copy of the required ID for each test.

There's another problem with the way you obtain the text value.

Without a return statement the `.then()` command passes on whatever subject it receives to the next command. See [then- Yields](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/then.html#Yields)

> Additionally, the result of the last Cypress command in the callback function will be yielded as the new subject and flow into the next command ***if there is no return***.

So the `.should('not.equal', null)` is testing that the element isn't null, not that the text is not null.

A better way is to `.invoke('text')` which is equivalent to `$txt.text()` and yields the text value to the `.should()`.

Also `.should('not.equal', null)` won't test that the content is present, since an empty element returns an empty string from `element.text()`. Use `.should('not.equal', '')` instead.

**Saving via an Alias**

```js
describe('grabbing ID for use in multiple tests', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('my-page-1.html')
    cy.get('#MYID')
      .invoke('text')
      .as('mySavedID')
  })

  it('ID should not be null', () => {

    cy.get('@mySavedID')
      .should('not.equal', '')

  })

  it('ID should be found in table', () => {

    cy.visit('app/navigate-to-new-page-2.html');
    cy.get('@mySavedID').then(myID => {
      cy.get('#myTable').find('td').contains(myID);
    })

  })
})
```

---

**Saving by queuing the setting of the variable**

The alias pattern may not be ideal if visiting page #1 is time consuming.

In this case, you can save the variable via a custom command. The difference is that the code you had within the `.then()` is moved into a command which is queued, so the async problem does not occur.

```js
describe('grabbing ID for use in multiple tests', () => {

  let savedVariable;

  Cypress.Commands.add("saveVariable", {prevSubject: true}, (value) => {
    savedVariable = value;
  });

  it('id should not be null', () => {

    cy.visit('my-page-1')
    cy.get('#someId')
      .invoke('text')
      .should('not.equal', '')
      .saveVariable()

    // OR test the variable separately like this

    cy.wrap(savedVariable)
      .should('not.equal', '')
  })

  it('id should be found in table', () => {

    cy.visit('my-page-2');
    cy.get('#myTable').find('td').contains(savedVariable);

  })
})
```

**NOTE**
The above is valid if the two pages are in the same domain, e.g two pages of a SPA. Otherwise, the test runner resets itself when a new domain is encountered, and all javascript variables are lost.

Comment: This super long and not a clear answer. Could you please modify it. I have the same problem and didn't get how you solved it.

Comment: Hey @Rsaleh, unfortunately this problem is difficult to explain. The key thing to understand is that Cypress has a command queue which runs asynchronously from the javascript in the test, so things happen out of order. You can observe the execution order by putting `console.log()` statements in at various points.

Comment: I actually fixed my issue using then() suggestion but the bad thing is that I have nested steps just to make sure that all inside then will only start after the before then action. 
Yes cy.log() is useful too. Thank you @Richard

Answer (score 4):

Save data at the plugins level and access it by tasks. Other levels get reloaded when `cy.visit` is called. Add `data` and tasks to `plugins/index.js`:

```
// plugins/index.js   
/// <reference types="cypress" />
module.exports = (on, config) => {

  // data will be stored here
  const data = {};

  // configuring tasks
  on('task', {
    setValue: (params) => {
      const { key, value } = params;
      data[key] = value;
      return value;
    },
    getValue: (params) => {
      const { key } = params;
      return data[key] || null;
    }
  })        
}
```

And use in scenario:

```
// my.spec.js
/// <reference types="cypress" />
context('keeps data safe when changing pages', () => {
  it('visits first page and saves data', () => {
    return cy.visit('https://google.com').then(() => {
      // saving data 
      return cy.task('setValue', { key: 'visited', value: 'google' });
    })
  });

  it('visits another page and checks that data is available', () => {
    return cy.visit('https://example.com').then(() => {
      // getting data
      return cy.task('getValue', { key: 'visited' });
    }).then((value) => {
      expect(value).to.equal('google');
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: This is great! Just remember: you'll have to wrap your return value.. `cy.task('getValue', { key: 'visited' }).then( (response) { DO YOU MAGIC HERE WITH response });`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's a good idea, but you can save data on the Cypress global object.

```js
context('Pass data via the Cypress object', () => {

  before(() => {
    Cypress._savedData = {}
  })

  it('visits first page and saves data', () => {

    cy.visit('https://google.com');
    cy.get('#MYID')
      .should('not.equal', null)
      .then($el => Cypress._savedData[myID] = $el.text() )

  });

  it('visits another page and checks that data is available', () => {

    cy.visit('https://example.com');
    cy.get('#myTable').find('td').contains(Cypress._savedData[myID]);

  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, since you are having page navigations, using aliases may not work, especially if the variable gets accessed before the alias is created (due to asynchronous execution and queuing of `then` blocks).

The simplest way to set a variable is to make use of the browser's `window` object and assigning the value to the `sessionStorage`

snippet -

```
var myID;
 cy.get('#MYID').
        then(($txt) => {
            window.sessionStorage.setItem(myID, $txt.text());
        })
       .should('not.equal', null);
```

It can be accessed within the test file (even from another test case) as follows -

```
let myID = window.sessionStorage.getItem('myID');
cy.get('#myTable').find('td').contains(myID);
```

However, please note that this is an anti-pattern, making one test rely on the output of another. It is described in the [Cypress Best Practices](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Having-Tests-Rely-On-The-State-Of-Previous-Tests) as well.